# Generic method T type is the constraint type, not the real type of the passed object

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have this generic method with a constraint for `ILogicPointContext`.
This method calls other generic methods with the same constraint, but the code throws exception since I need the type to be the correct one, not the interface type.

```cs
public void DoSomething<TContext>(TContext ctx)
    where TContext : ILogicPointContext
{
    var typeOfCtx = ctx.GetType();  // CcpContex
    var typeOfT = typeof(TContext); // ILogicPointContext
    ...
```

I have another similar method where the generic type of the method is the generic type of the object I pass to him and this works fine

```cs
private void InsertStepDefinition<TContext>(PipelineStepDefinition<TContext> stepInfo)
    where TContext : ILogicPointContext
```

In this case TContext is not the interface but the correct type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Who is calling who?

Comment: Could be a `PipelineStepDefinition<TContext>` that should be a `TContext` or vice versa.

Comment: What is the type and message of the thrown exception and what is the reason for throwing it? If a method has a generic type constraint, but at runtime it has further constraints on the type, you have to check message and code to fullfill these constraints. We can't really help, cause we don't know your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic resolves automatically when called with variable types (not calling the method with <>).

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo var1 = new Foo();
    ILogicPointContext var2 = var1;
    
    DoSomething(var1); //outputs Foo: generic resolution is automatically done on variable type
    DoSomething(var2); //outputs ILogicPointContext, for the same reason
}



interface ILogicPointContext{}
class Foo:ILogicPointContext{}

void DoSomething<TContext>(TContext ctx)
    where TContext : ILogicPointContext
{    
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(TContext).Name);
}
```

The second output is the actual type of TContext, the type the generic is 'created' with and is used within the method.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that the context was retrieved using this method `LogicPointContext GetContext(string logicPointCode)`.
Using `TContext GetContext<TContext>(string logicPointCode) where TContext : ILogicPointContext` resolved the problem. The issue now is that I have to know the type in advance

Comment: That makes sense. If you are absolutely sure the result is a `CcpContex`, you can cast it to one first, but that can cause runtime errors. If it really is imperative to know the actual type of the object, gettype() is probably safer.
Out of curiosity, why do you need the exact type?

Comment: I have this dictionary where are stored configurations for building a pipeline, and since there are different types of context in the application I decided to use the type name as the dictionary key for those settings